# Why I can't downgrade npm package PhantomJS?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, package.json

Some time ago I installed npm package phantomjs. Now my unit tests are not working. PhantomJS browser is not capturing.

I want to downgrade version of package phantomjs.

I found, that I can delete phantomjs by `npm uninstall phantomjs`. I did this and console says that everything is ok.

I tried command `npm v phantomjs | grep version`. It says phantomjs is installed and its version is 2.1.3. Looks like phantomjs was not uninstalled.

I tried to fully remove node_modules from my project and write install command again: `npm install`. When I checked version I got 2.1.3. In my package.json phantomjs described as `"phantomjs": "^1.9.19"`. So, I expect, that versions will be `>=1.9.19 < 2.0.0`. Well, it is 1.9.19. I checked version manually in >node_modules\phantomjs\package.json` and it is 1.9.19.

So what version is actually installed? Why versions are not same in packages.json and by command `npm v xxx`?

Comment: ^1.9.19 is over v1.9.19 I believe

Comment: No, its not. Look this: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

Comment: Is it possible you installed the package globally?

Comment: Of course it is possible. How I can uninstall it then? I tried npm uninstall -g phantomjs and console says there are no such package. Should I use another command to uninstall globally installed package?